# What could cause fast Fourier transform to give complex conjugate of the intended result?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, dft

I have 2 real time series $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, after fft it should become $\tilde{X}(f)$ and $\tilde{Y}(f)$. Then I need to normalize $\tilde{X}(f)$ with $\tilde{Y}(f)$ : $\tilde{X}(f)/\tilde{Y}(f)=\tilde{Z}(f)$

However fft gives me $\tilde{Z}^*(f)$ instead (the sign of the imaginary part is inverted).

What could have caused this ? I know $x(-t)$ and $y(-t)$ can cause $\tilde{Z}^*(f)$, but $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ have the correct physical meaning.

Comment: Well then something about your vector manipulation or division is wrong.  A common trap in Matlab is that the ' operator and .' operator are different.  The first is conjugate transpose while the second is just transpose.

Comment: I would be easier for us if you could include your matlab code.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the inverse FFT (IFFT) instead of FFT would cause a phase inversion.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the Fourrier Transform formula is :

$${{\hat {x}}(\nu )=\int _{-\infty }^{+\infty }x(t)\,\mathrm {e} ^{-2{\rm {i}}\pi\nu t}\,\mathrm {d} t}.$$

Are you sure you didn't forget the minus (-) sign in the exponential ? In this case, because $x(t)$ is real, You will effectively find the conjugate of ${\hat {x}}(\nu )$ at the end.

Comment: Please check my updated question. I used Matlab fft function so there is no way the fft itself is wrong.